# Reading txt file into python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I python rookie here. I have multiple text files each with the following format of floats 1x10, 1x10 and 10x10

```
0.0551 1500.0 [273.639, 273.331, 273.021, 272.711, 272.399, 272.087, 271.773, 271.46, 271.145]

0.0553 1532.5 [272.422, 273.96, 273.021, 273.321, 272.494, 273.129, 271.12, 271.23, 271.889]

0.0555 1560.0 [273.234, 273.44, 273.133, 272.065, 272.234, 272.012, 271.942, 271.43, 271.145]

0.0558 1582.5 [272.45, 273.011, 273.45, 273.331, 272.321, 273.234, 271.34, 271.531, 271.932]
```

I would like to read them as a column as following to be able to plot them:

```py
column1 = [0.0551,0.0553,0.0555,0.0558,....]

column2 = [1500.0,1532.5,1560.0,1582.5,....]

column3 = [[273.639, 273.331, 273.021, 272.711, 272.399, 272.087, 271.773, 271.46, 271.145],[272.422, 273.96, 273.021, 273.321, 272.494, 273.129, 271.12, 271.23, 271.889],[273.234, 273.44, 273.133, 272.065, 272.234, 272.012, 271.942, 271.43, 271.145],[272.45, 273.011, 273.45, 273.331, 272.321, 273.234, 271.34, 271.531, 271.932]]
```

I tried numpy loadtxt and numerous other functions but was never able to successfully read them in python. What is the best way to read the text file in the desired format?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried that doesn't work?

Comment: If you have access to the file-writing routine, avoid those `[`, then it's exactly `np.loadtxt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file structure is kinda weird, you should clean it upstream.
Anyway here's the function to load your data. If the file structure changes too much, the function may not work.

```
def load_data(file):
    cols = [[] for _ in range(3)]
    to_remove = ['[', ']', '\n']
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if len(line) > 1:
                split_line = line
                for x in to_remove: split_line = split_line.replace(x, '') 
                split_line = split_line.split(' ', 2)
                cols[0].append(float(split_line[0]))
                cols[1].append(float(split_line[1]))
                cols[2].append([float(i) for i in split_line[2].split(',')])
    return cols
```

Comment: Thank you, I get an error stating ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.1\t1.0\t196.2444277073552,' My first row of data is 0.1 1.0 [196.2444277073552, 196.21722702995334, .....]

Comment: Hum, as I said if the structure changes, the function won't work. because the spacing between float are "\t" and not " " (spaces) anymore. So the split(" ") method doesn't work. change `split_line = split_line.split(' ', 2)` into `split_line = split_line.split('\t', 2)`